Grafana not picking up the url, username and password specified in datasource.yml
I have datasource.yml file in provisioning/datasources.
apiVersion: 1
datasources:
  - name: 'MongoDB'
    type: meln5674-mongodb-community
    access: proxy
    basicAuth: false
    editable: true
    enabled: true
    jsonData:
      connection: mongodb+srv://user:password@sandbox.ghdtc.mongodb.net/
      user: ''
    secureJsonData:
      password: ''

Problem 1: this configuration is not getting picked up automatically. I need to manually add the details inside grafana data source and test.
Problem2: Also the variables have been migrated but they show no values which leave me no other option but to create them again.
Problem 3: If i pass grafana.ini file with anonymous login enabled I do not see an option to edit the data source. What should be the configuration in grafana.ini so that anonymous login will be enabled but I will be able to edit data source.
I tried removing all configuration from grafana.ini and kept only anonymous login enabled but I could not find an option to edit data source. Also for problem 1 I tried adding editable: true which does not work if i am passing grafana.ini.
